# How can i Add pages to this type of bottom bar?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been trying to create a chat app, and I am new to flutter. How can I add pages to the tabbed view of the bottom bar with their specific pages? For example, a chat screen for the chat tab and a profile page for the profile tab. The navigation between the pages should be fluid.

Here is my bottom_bar.dart code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:messenger_clone/animated_bottom_bar.dart';

class ButtomBar extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'buttom_bar';
  final List<BarItem> barItems = [
    BarItem(
      text: "Chats",
      iconData: Icons.chat_bubble_outline,
      color: Colors.indigo,
    ),
    BarItem(
      text: "People",
      iconData: Icons.people_outline,
      color: Colors.pinkAccent,
    ),
    BarItem(
      text: "Search",
      iconData: Icons.search,
      color: Colors.yellow.shade900,
    ),
    BarItem(
      text: "Profile",
      iconData: Icons.person_outline,
      color: Colors.teal,
    ),
  ];

  @override
  _ButtomBar createState() =>
      _ButtomBar();
}

class _ButtomBar
    extends State<ButtomBar> {
  int selectedBarIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: AnimatedBottomBar(
          barItems: widget.barItems,
          animationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 150),
          barStyle: BarStyle(
            fontSize: 20.0,
            iconSize: 30.0
          ),
          onBarTap: (index) {
            setState(() {
              selectedBarIndex = index;
            });
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

So the, Clicking on different icons navigate to others like a scroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when apps have bottomBars, they usually reload the Scaffold body instead of sliding to the next screen. Check Youtube, Reddit, WhatsApp, they all rebuild the body.
In order to do that, you just have to create a list of Widgets like that:

`List<Widget> screenList = [HomePage(), ChatPage(), SearchPage()];`
and then you put it in your Scaffold:

```
return Scaffold(
      body: screenList[selectedBarIndex]
      bottomNavigationBar: AnimatedBottomBar(
          ...
      )
    );
```

Now if you REALLY want it to slide, it will be more complicated, as you probably have to create a custom PageRoute.
Take a look at this article: https://uxdesign.cc/level-up-flutter-page-transition-choreographing-animations-across-screens-efb5ea105fca

He made a persistent AppBar, so it must be similar.